# How to save installation path to a file during installation?

Tags: inno-setup

My application is installed by InnoSetup.
The user may change the installation folder when he starts install the application.

I'd like to store the installation path right after the user decided about it (during the installation process), into an INI file (My application holds an INI file that is stored in the roaming folder).

Is that possible? Can you tell me how to?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can simply add an [`[INI]`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_inisection.htm) section entry like this into your script. There you can pass the [`{app}`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_consts.htm#app) constant, which holds the selected directory path:

```
[INI]
Filename: "MyProg.ini"; Section: "InstallSettings"; Key: "InstallPath"; String: "{app}"
```